# Transactions billing on Windows Azure

Tags: transactions, azure

My company currently has some serious problem. We've got an application as showcase on Azure which makes use of 1 web role, 1 worker role, a message queue and table storage, but in very moderate rates.

We are billed for 8 days now and our billing for "storage transactions" seems to be abnormally high. We are at 25 EUR now which is really too much looking at the very limited size of our little application.

Thus I just wanted to know: what exactly is 1 storage transaction on Windows Azure that we are billed for? Is it table storage, blob storage or message queue transaction as well? Perhaps we could make some conclusions afterwards.

Thanks, Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/hanuk/archive/2009/08/03/azure-pricing-details-are-much-simpler-than-the-other-cloud-providers.aspx):

*Storage Transactions   $0.01/10K transactions  Every CRUDy (Create, Read, Update, Delete) transaction into Azure Queues (this is the only charge for the queues), Azure Tables, Azure Blobs will incur this charge.*

I know that they have had some issues with billing, and reset some of the counters. I don't know if it had anything to do with transactions...

Comment: Thanks, then we would have to investigate the high volume. Currently we can't explain it.

Answer (score 1):

**Azure Storage Transactions:**

Each individual Blob, Table and Queue REST request to the storage service is considered as a potential transaction for billing. Applications can then control their transaction costs by controlling how often and how many requests they send to the storage service. We analyze each request received and then classify it as billable or not billable based upon our ability to process the request and the request’s outcome.

[Click here to get more details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The transactions could be referring to storage transactions, or data transfers - both are variable cost items on the pricing sheet. The pricing is listed out at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/ so it shoudn't be too hard to figure out where you are picking up the high usage.